# Get Airflow DAG Task Dependencies from Airflow Metadata

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

We are trying to analyze our DAG tasks over time, and want to be able to query the data in Airflow's (v2) metadata database.

A simple example would be a DAG with `a > b > c`.

By querying the TaskInstance metadata, and we can get all the individual task run details for a, b, and c. However in the TaskInstance database, there isn't information there that c depends on b, b depends on a.

I've looked at the other objects in the metadata environment such as `DagRun`, `DagModel`, etc, but the information on the upstream/downstream for each task isn't there. Is there a way to get the task dependencies from the metadata so that we can join it to the TaskInstance data, so we can track the lineage of task execution by querying the metadatabase instead of from the UI?

Answer (score 0):

how're doing? Try table named as serialized_dag. There's a information about dependencies dag.

Comment: Hi! I tried querying the `serializedDagModel` class: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/serialized_dag/index.html, but the table only has high level information for each DAG, and does not go into the individual dependencies of each task for each DAG. Is there a command to extract the underlying DAG dependency information?

Comment: Hi! I will send a query that i used to in sql. There's a coluna named as 'data' with task_groups and childrens in json. I'm not in computer right now, but tomorrow earlier   i send

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully that would work :) AWS Support came back to me to say it's not possible, but if your approach works that would be awesome

Comment: Any updates Lipe?

Comment: My approaches are as follows: the first is to go directly to the task instance as follows, getting the minimum and maximum execution date of the DAG. So we can calculate the difference and have the duration time.

Comment: @BenL the first approach is:



with duration as (select 
    dag_run.dag_id, 
    min(task_instance.start_date) as started_at, 
    max(task_instance.end_date)  as ended_at
from 
    dag_run 
inner join task_instance on dag_run.dag_id = task_instance.dag_id 
and dag_run.execution_date >= (current_date - 1) 
and dag_run.run_id = task_instance.run_id
and dag_run.dag_id like '%your_dag_id_here%'
group by
    dag_run.dag_id
)
select * from duration

Comment: The second approach is to go straight to the 'serialzed_dag' table and get part by part: first get the dag part, then collect the information from the tasks_group, and finally the filters to get the time of each one and so the dependencies are collected.

Comment: @BenL the second approach is: with dag_information as(

select data::json->'dag' as teste, dag_id from serialized_dag
), task_group as(
 select teste::json->'_task_group' as grupo, dag_id from dag_information
), childrens as(
 select grupo::json->'children' as children, dag_id from task_group
), all_tables as (
  select json_object_keys(children) as table_name, dag_id from childrens
)

in the next  comment I will put the rest of the query

Comment: all_data as (
   select dag_run.dag_id, task_instance.start_date as start_date, task_instance.task_id as task_id,  task_instance.duration as duracao
from
    dag_run inner join task_instance on dag_run.dag_id = task_instance.dag_id inner join all_tables on dag_run.dag_id = all_tables.dag_id 
    and dag_run.execution_date >= (current_date - 1)
    and dag_run.run_id = task_instance.run_id
    and task_instance.task_id = all_tables.table_name
    and dag_run.dag_id like 'your_dag_id_here'
group by dag_run.dag_id, task_instance.task_id, task_instance.start_date, task_instance.duration
)

Comment: select * from all_data  is the rest. @BenL

Comment: In children has all dependencie for a singles task.

Comment: Thanks Lipe! The query doesn't fully work because the table `task_instance` does not have the `run_id` column. Could I also ask how you are accessing the `serialized_dag` table? There does not seem to be that table and the way to access it from online research seems to be via a DAG file to call the objects